# Edit a .txt file with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want a user on my website to type in a string. I want this string to be stored in a txt file. When another user types in a string I want this string to be stored in a seperate line in the txt file, so I can read all the data, which was typed in later.

I searched the web for a good solution, because I don't know how to edit a txt file with JavaScript. Unfortionately everything I found is written in jQuery, which I did not learn yet. Does somebody know a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: There's not a simple solution. You will need server side code to do this. You're client side javascript will post the string to your server side code, that code (written in whatever you want) can then concat the string to the end of your text file. You'll have to learn more about general web development, javascript, and whatever language you want to use server side.

Comment: You can't do that from the client side. I'm going to take a wild guess and assume this is for a wordpress blog, you need to search for solutions how to do that in php.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't on the client, you can on the server.

Bigger question is why? If you want to store user input so they have it later you can use [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or even just a `cookie` to store it.

If you want to save it on the server text files are usually a bad idea - there are a lot of server side storage options that are better than plain text, but you'll need to provide a lot more information for us to help on that.

Comment: Ok, I will try it with a database.